# Different assignments in pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

As you can see in the code, I assign different values to the pointer:

1. fin->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
2. fin = nuevo_nodo;

Does this make any difference?

```
void append(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin, int valor){
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    nuevo_nodo->valor = valor;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = nullptr;
    if(empty(frente)){
        frente = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    else{
        fin->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    fin = nuevo_nodo;
}
```

Comment: Your question appears to be an *XY Problem*. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You appear to be struggling with how to form a linked-list from your nodes. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I see a difference `0x56021db72e ->f<- 0` and  `0x56021db72e ->d<- 0`

Comment: The output you show contains 4 lines, and 3 distinct addresses. Second and fourth line are the same - but that's not surprising, as they print `ptr` and `ptr3`, and the very last line before the output is `ptr = ptr3;` So what do you mean by "no difference" - what did you expect to be different from what else?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: What's wrong with the new code? What outcome do you expect from it, and what do you observe instead? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, the difference between assigning with the = and the -> in the else.

Comment: The two assignments modify two different objects, of course. One modifies `fin->siguiente`, the other modifies `fin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have changed to question, I will change the answer too.

When your else part runs, you assign 'fin->siguiente = nuevo_nodo'. Say 'fin' was initally at address 1000 and 'nuevo_nodo' as at address 2000.
fin's **siguiente** pointer is pointing to address 2000.

In the next line you assign 'fin = nuevo_nodo', so fin now points to 2000 address and there is no 'siguiente' pointer assigned(line 4).